# UIScrollView contentInset Autolayout issue

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a custom UIView which has a UIScrollView as a subview. My problem is when the view resizes, I wish to resize the scroll view and also reset its contentInset to this:

```
  scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.bounds.height/2, left: 0, bottom: self.bounds.height/2, right: 0)
```

How do I do this using Auto layout?

Answer (score 1):

Given a view layout like this:

[image: storyboard layout]

You can automatically change the `UIScrollView` `contentInset` property when the container view `MyView` changes size, using the `didSet` property of the view's `bounds` property:

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView {

    weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: bounds.height / 2, left: 0, bottom: bounds.height / 2, right: 0)
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: MyView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myView.scrollView = scrollView
    }
}
```

It's important to note that you may not see the changes to the content inset when they happen, because the content of the scroll view does not automatically scroll to the edge when it's content insets are reduced, for example. You'll have to play with the scroll to see that the content insets have really changed.

Comment: Which brings us to another problem, observing bounds change on UIView. Will this setter be invoked, always? Some answers, such as https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/104489, suggest it is not reliable.

Comment: Hmm I see. Any way that you can directly hook into the event that resizes your scroll view? E.g. the device orientation change, or whatever event is causing your scroll view to change size.